# Rename file by swaping text - swap date string at the begin of a file name

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, sh

I need to rename files by swaping some text. I had for example :

`eMail - 2015-11-28 1926.eml
second mail - 2016-07-26 1245.eml
third mL 2016-11-26 1410.eml
4-mail 2017-05-21 0105.eml`

...

and I want them

`2015-11-28 1926 eMail - .eml
2016-07-26 1245 second mail - .eml
2016-11-26 1410 third mL.eml
2017-05-21 0105 4-mail.eml`

... a part of a way you could find here:

i tried 
`ls *.pdf | awk -F"[_.]" '{print "mv "$0" "$2"_"$1"."$3}' | sh`

from > 
[swap filename example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444825/move-last-part-of-filename-to-front)

that was running goog, but not practical for `.eml`-files.

[second swap filename example looks good too](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444825/move-last-part-of-filename-to-front)

but i am a bit stupid to solve the problem

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and mention why that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If `regex` is available (`bash` version >= 3.2), please try the following:

```
for f in *.eml; do
    if [[ $f =~ ^(.+)\ +([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\ +[0-9]+)\.eml$ ]]; then
        newname="${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.eml"
        mv -- "$f" "$newname"
    fi
done
```

- The regex breaks down the filename into "date + number substring" and
  "preceding substring" then assigns bash variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}`
  to the captured groups.
- Then `newname` is assigned to a swapped filename.